# Python Pandas, how to group list of dict and sort

Tags: python, database, pandas, bigdata

I have a list of dict like:

```
data = [
    {'ID': '000681', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testA': '11'},
    {'ID': '000682', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testA': '-'},
    {'ID': '000683', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testA': '13'},
    {'ID': '000684', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testA': '14'},
    {'ID': '000681', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testB': '15'},
    {'ID': '000682', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testB': '16'},
    {'ID': '000683', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testB': '17'},
    {'ID': '000684', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testB': '-'}
]
```

How to use Pandas to get data like:

```
data = [
    {'ID': '000683', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testA': '13',  'testB': '17'},
    {'ID': '000681', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testA': '11',  'testB': '15'},
    {'ID': '000684', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testA': '14',  'testB': '-'},
    {'ID': '000682', 'type': 'B:G+',  'testA': '-',  'testB': '16'}

]
```

Same `ID` and same `type` to one col and sorted by `testA` and `testB` values

sorted :   both `testA` and `testB` have value and lager value of `testA+testB` at the top.

Answer (score 2):

First convert columns to numeric with replace non numeric to integers and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)    
c = ['testA','testB']
df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

df1 = df.groupby(['ID','type'])[c].sum(min_count=1).sort_values(c).fillna('-').reset_index()
print (df1)
       ID  type testA testB
0  000681  B:G+    11    15
1  000683  B:G+    13    17
2  000684  B:G+    14     -
3  000682  B:G+     -    16
```

If want sorting by sum of both columns use [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
c = ['testA','testB']
df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

df2 = df.groupby(['ID','type'])[c].sum(min_count=1)
df2 = df2.iloc[(-df2).sum(axis=1).argsort()].fillna('-').reset_index()
print (df2)
       ID  type testA testB
0  000683  B:G+    13    17
1  000681  B:G+    11    15
2  000682  B:G+     -    16
3  000684  B:G+    14     -
```